# Regex matching for optional characters including question mark

Tags: regex, python-3.x

My string looks like this: "https://google.com/bar/foobar?count=1" or it could be "https://google.com/bar/foobar"

I want to extract the value `foobar` - it appears after `/bar` and has an optional `?`

My regex looks like  this:
`m = re.match(r'(.*)/bar/(.*)((\?)(.*))?', data)`

When I use this regex over example 2: `"https://google.com/bar/foobar"` I get two groups
`('https://google.com', 'foobar', None, None, None)`

When I use this regex on the first example: `"https://google.com/bar/foobar?count=1"` I get

`('https://google.com', 'foobar?count=3', None, None, None)`

But I would like the second group to just be `foobar` without the `?count=3`
How would I achieve that?

My understanding so far is

`(.*)/bar/(.*)((\?)(.*))?` is as follows:
`(.*)` matches the first part of the string. `\?` matches the `?` and `((\?)(.*))` matches `?count=3` and this is enclosed in `?` because it is supposed to be optional.

Comment: `((\?)(.*))?` is optional, so the second `(.*)` grabs the rest of the string after the last `/bar/` in the string.

Comment: I would strongly suggest that you use an existing Python library to parse your URLs.  That library will be already written, tested and debugged for many years and will undoubtedly cover corner cases that you might not have considered.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am trying to understand how regex's work. This is not used in production.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Yeah the reason it is optional is because `?count=3` can be optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `*` in `.*` of your regular expression makes it greedy. The first occurance of `.*` in your pattern would match till the end of the url as the rest of the matches are optional. To avoid this, you have to make your regexp non-greedy by adding a `?` after `*`

And you need to anchor your regex pattern with a `$` at the end, as otherwise the non-greedy ptrn wont match anything.

```
>>> data = "https://google.com/bar/foobar?count=1"
>>> re.match(r'(.*)/bar/(.*?)((\?)(.*?))?$', data).groups()
('https://google.com', 'foobar', '?count=1', '?', 'count=1')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you give more intuition on why this works? I understand that `$` is for end of line.

Comment: Added bit more explanation

Answer (score 1):

Use a URL parser to extract the *path* component, then you can simplify your regex: `.*/bar/(.*)`

```
import re
import urllib.parse

examples = [
    "https://google.com/bar/foobar",
    "https://google.com/bar/foobar?count=1",
    ]

for ex in examples:
    path = urllib.parse.urlparse(ex).path
    result = re.search(r'.*/bar/(.*)', path)
    print(result.group(1))
```

Output:

```
foobar
foobar
```